# Сделать подчеркивание как underline только без промежутков

Tags: html, css, html5, вёрстка

Можно ли как-нибудь в css сделать подчеркивание текста (вне зависимости от кол-ва контента) по высоте как underline, но без промежутков от букв?

[image: Пример]

```css
a {
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: #353535; 
  text-decoration: none;
}

.blog__link-border {
    border-bottom: 2px inset #353535;
}

.blog__link-under {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<h2>Пример: border, далеко от текста</h2>
<a class="blog__link-border" href="blank.html">10 способов сервировки фруктовых щербетов к столу</a>

<h2>Пример: uderline, промежутки</h2>
<a class="blog__link-under" href="blank.html">10 способов сервировки фруктовых щербетов к столу</a>
```

Comment: Так border будет подчеркивать всегда самую нижнюю строку..

Comment: @InDevX Да, я знаю, но у меня в коде страницы почему-то каждая строка подчеркивается через border)))

Comment: [text-decoration-skip-ink: none;](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration-skip-ink)   наверно

Comment: @MaximLensky Спасибо, да подходит, но он вроде в Safari не поддерживается.

Answer (score 1):

Можно градиентом...

```css
a {
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: #353535;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: #353535;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-image: linear-gradient(0deg, black 0%, white 1px);
  background-position-y: -3px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<h2>Пример: border, далеко от текста</h2>
<a class="blog__link-border" href="blank.html">10 способов сервировки фруктовых щербетов к столу</a>

<h2>Пример: uderline, промежутки</h2>
<a class="blog__link-under" href="blank.html">10 способов сервировки фруктовых щербетов к столу</a>


<h2>Пример: uderline, промежутки</h2>
<a class="blog__link-under" href="blank.html">10 способов сервировки фруктовых щербетов к столу10 способов сервировки фруктовых щербетов к столу10 способов сервировки фруктовых щербетов к столу10 способов сервировки фруктовых щербетов к столу10 способов сервировки фруктовых щербетов к столу10 способов сервировки фруктовых щербетов к столу10 способов сервировки фруктовых щербетов к столу10 способов сервировки фруктовых щербетов к столу10 способов сервировки фруктовых щербетов к столу10 способов сервировки фруктовых щербетов к столу</a>
```